# Why main domain will send the password reset email when request on subdomain?

Tags: wordpress

I have a multi-network WordPress.

Main Domain: ABC.com
Subdomain: xxx.ABC.com

When I request a password reset from xxx.abc.com. My main domain will also send the password reset email. Any advice?

Answer (score 0):

Use SMTP on subdomain

Both abc.com and xxx.abc.com should use different mail server

You can try any free email SMTP service like

sendgrid.com

Comment: Yes, both domains are using the SMTP plugin. Unfortunately, it's still sent twice the reset email.

Comment: both using different mail server ?